# Why doesn't my persisted model have ID and other attributes returned from the server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am attempting to create a new record using Ember Data (the latest beta release, number 6). I seem to have most things working but creating and persisting a new model is not setting the attributes returned from the server on the model (including the id).

Here's the code I have in my controller.

```js
actions:
  cancel: ->
    @transitionToRoute('brews.index')
  save: (brew) ->
    self = this
    brew.save().then( ->
      console.log "Brew id is #{brew.get('id')}"
      console.log "Brew effciency is #{brew.get('efficiency')}"
      self.transitionToRoute('recipe', brew)
    )
```

The output console logging is returning `null` for the ID and `undefined` for the other attribute.

I believe my json is being returned properly from the server:

```js
{"brew":{"id":57,"name":"Yadda Yadda","created_at":"2014-02-16T23:44:46Z","efficiency":75}}
```

I'm using the DS.ActiveModelAdapter. Any ideas why this ember isn't seeing the attributes returned from the server?

Comment: Could you post your model?

Comment: Here is the model in question: https://gist.github.com/sohara/9043333

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an argument with your promise function?

This way in that function scope it can access the saved instance returned by the promise, with the id available.

```
actions:
  cancel: ->
    @transitionToRoute('brews.index')
  save: (brew) ->
    self = this
    brew.save().then( (b)->
      console.log "Brew id is #{b.get('id')}"
      console.log "Brew effciency is #{b.get('efficiency')}"
      self.transitionToRoute('recipe', b)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that now, but it doesn't resolve the issue. I also logged `b == brew` to the console and it returns true, which implies that the promise returns the same object, no need to pass it as a function argument. Also, in the Ember inspector, the object never gets an ID or other attributes assigned.

Comment: What does the 'model' hook look like for this route?

Comment: I didn't use a model hook, just a setupController hook. In the setupController hook choose the controller to use and then I assign the model to it's content property. Do I need a model hook as well? Here is the setupController hook: https://gist.github.com/sohara/9044412